# PyTables and HDF5: Massive overhead for tree data

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

I have a tree data structure that I want to save to disk. Thus, HDF5 with its internal tree structure seemed to be the perfect candidate. However, so far the data overhead is massive, by a factor of 100!

A test tree contains roughly 100 nodes, where leaves usually contain no more than 2 or 3 data items (like doubles). If I take the entire tree and just pickle it, it is about 21kB large. Yet, if I use PyTables and map the tree structure one to one to the HDF5 file, the file takes 2.4MB (!) disk space. Is the overhead that big?

The problem is that the overhead does not seem to be constant but linearly scales with the size of my tree data (as well as increasing nodes as increasing data per leaf, i.e. enlarging rows of the leaf tables).

Did I miss something regarding PyTables, like enabling compression (I thought PyTables does it by default)? What could possibly be the reason for this massive overhead?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you have such small leaves? I'd guess that this is the reason for your large overhead.

Comment: It is not determined from the start how these leaves look like (how many they are etc.), they are rather independent and the data is not related directly. So I would prefer them to be separate. Still I would not mind some overhead, but a thousand times larger seems intractable. I mean storing 100 nodes needs 2.4 MB, really?

Comment: Pre-allocating a few K per leaf seems like a sensible default, doesn't it?

Comment: Oops, PyTables does not compress by default! If I add `filters=Filters(complevel=9)` to every table creation I can reduce the filesize by a factor of 15. I'm gonna see how far I can push it :-).

Comment: @SmCaterpillar Looks like it's working ok? If so, please post and accept your own answer as the solution. It might help someone else and will be easier to notice than the comments.

Comment: I did, but I have to wait 2 days to be able to accept my own answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I have found a way to massively reduce the file size. The point is, despite my prior believes, PyTables does NOT apply compression per default.

You can achieve this by using `Filters`.

Here is an example how that works:

```
   import pytables as pt

   hdf5_file = pt.openFile(filename = 'myhdf5file.h5', 
                           mode='a', 
                           title='How to compress data') 
   # for pytables >= 3 the method is called `open_file`, 
   # other methods are renamed analogously

   myfilters = Filters(complevel=9, complib='zlib')

   mydescitpion = {'mycolumn': pt.IntCol()} # Simple 1 column table

   mytable = hdf5_file.createTable(where='/', name='mytable',
                                     description=mydescription,
                                     title='My Table',
                                     filters=myfilters)
   #Now you can happily fill the table...
```

The important line here is `Filters(complevel=9, complib='zlib')`. It specifies the
compression level `complevel` and the compression algorithm `complib`. Per default the level is set to 0, that means compression is disabled, whereas 9 is the highest compression level. For details on how compression works: [HERE IS A LINK TO THE REFERENCE](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/helper_classes.html#filtersclassdescr).

Next time, I better stick to RTFM :-) (although I did, but I missed the line "One of the beauties of PyTables is that it supports compression on tables and arrays, although it is not used by default")

Comment: I've fallen into this trap before as well. It's probably right that compression is disabled by default, but it just doesn't jump out from the docs as often/clearly as it probably should. I highly recommend the blosc compression lib if you are after best IO performance (of course your data/app may determine which compression lib is best).

Comment: I hesitate to use blosc. If I store data using blosc I can no longer browse and view it with hdfview. If I open a Table or Array saved via blosc an error is thrown.